# metrizability of weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology, metrizability

I have a problem with a line at the end of an example who tolds this:
let $(E,||-||)$ be a separable Banach space. If there exist a weak Cauchy sequence who doesn't converge weakly to an element of $E$, then the weak topology on $E$ is not metrizable.

I can't undestand why necessairly the weak topology is not metrizable by the condition about the Cauchy sequence.

I think that must exist a result like that, who prove the above assertion, but I don't  know if this result is valid:

If $ (E, ||-||) $ is a separable Banach space, then the metric space $ (E,d) $ is complete for all metric $ d $ whose induced topology is coarser than the topology induced by $ ||-|| $.

If this proposition is valid, (we know that the weak topology is the coarsest topology such that all linear functionals of the dual space are continuous,) so the first assertion will be proven.

PS: I do not want to use the fact that if $E$ is an infinite dimensional normed space, then the weak topology is not metrizable.

Comment: The result you are anticipating is false: $C[0,1]$ is a separable Banach space with the usual sup norm. Consider the norm $f \to \int_0^{1} |f|$. This gives a coarser topology but $C[0,1]$ is not complete under this metric. [Proof: identity map from $(C[0,1],||.||_{\infty}) \to (C[0,1],||.||_1$ is bijective and continuous. If the range space is complete then the  inverse map would be continuous; so there exists a constant $C$ such that  $\int_0^{1} |f| \geq C ||f||_{\infty}$ and this is false.

Comment: Thank you, now the problem is too hard to proove the first assertion :(

Comment: Do you know if this assertion can be valid? "Let $(E,d)$ and $(E',D)$ be two metric space. If $\forall (x_n)_n\in E$ and $\forall f\in E'$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\in E$". Because this proposition could be the answer to my question.

Comment: Yes, your assertion is valid and it follows by Uniform Boundedness Principle.